# Moment generating function properties: $3φ_X (t)$ and $φ_X (t) × φ_X (6t)$

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

Suppose that $φ_X (t)$ is the moment generating function of some random variable $X$. Are the following functions moment generating functions of some (other) random variables?

i. $3φ_X (t)$

I think this one isn't, because $3φ_X (t)=3E(e^{tX})=E(3e^{tX}), $ this can't be expressed as the expectation of an exponential power.

ii. $φ_X (t) × φ_X (6t)$

$φ_X (t) × φ_X (6t)=E(e^{tX})E(e^{6tX})=E(e^{tX+6tX})=E(e^{7tX})=φ_{7X} (t).$ I'm not too sure on whether I can merge the product of expectations into one expectation.

Is my reasoning for both the above statements correct?

Comment: Think harder: your i) is not a proof, your ii) uses $E(e^{tX})E(e^{6tX})=E(e^{tX+6tX})$ which is wrong in general.

Comment: In what direction do i think?

Comment: On i): If $\phi(t)$ is a moment generating function then what can be said about $\phi(0)$?

Comment: @drhab it's equal to 1

Comment: Well, do we have $3\phi_X(0)=1$?

Comment: @drhab Ahah....

Answer (score 1):

Hint on i): if $\phi(t)$ is a moment generating function then what can be said about $\phi(0)$?

Hints on ii)

- What are the looks of moment generating function of $cX$ expressed in $\phi_X$ where $c$ is constant?
- If $X,Y$ are independent then what are the looks of the moment generating function of $X+Y$ expressed in $\phi_X$ and $\phi_Y$?

Comment: For part ii of your hints, $\phi_{cX} (t)=E(e^{tcX})=\phi_{X} (ct)$ and mgf of $X+Y=\phi_{X} (t)\phi_{Y} (t)$

Comment: Yes, now let $Y$ have the same distribution as $6X$ and you are ready.

Comment: But why is X independent of itself. i.e why are X and Y=6X independent?

Comment: $X$ is not independent of itself and $Y\neq6X$. $X$ and $Y$ are taken independently but $Y$ must have *the same distribution* as $6X$. Two distinct dice are independent but have the same distribution.